# Knitr - Enable to compile R Sweave PDF with errors

Tags: r, pdf, knitr

I am using very often `knitr` to compile PDF with the great R Sweave doc format. 
However, very often the compiled code is huge and minor errors are hiding here and there. The document then fail to compile and I am often struggling to find where the errors are hidding. Many times I even (desperately) abandon the document and re-start all over again in a fresh one.

My question is : is it possible to enable the PDF to still get compiled with errors - basically like in many latex editors (Tex Studio) where to PDF is still produced even with errors in tables and so on.

I also wanted to know what was the *best practices* when working with R Sweave. 
For me, at the moment, I try to keep my codes in separate R scripts and then source them into the R Sweave document. This enables me to lighten a bit my `.Rnw` page and focus more on the writing. And also enables me to figure out more easily where the errors are. Any thoughts on this ?

Comment: I am pretty familiar with the problem that it may be difficult to trace back LaTeX errors when using `knitr`. Very often, the following helps me a lot: After `knitr` has run, open the TEX file in your preferred LaTeX editor and compile from there. This usually delivers me clearer error messages and error locations. Regarding the second part of your question, my preferred strategy is [code externalization](http://yihui.name/knitr/demo/externalization/) but the *best* setup depends on your use case.